# How can I produce a similar output from file reading in python but in php

Tags: python, php, fopen, fread

I have a program I am converting from python to PHP, basically it starts by reading a file and continues on to unpack the data. During the conversion I've realised that unpacking formats are different and tested this with the python output, though PHP does not produce the same output.

Is it possible to produce a similar output from the fopen and fread function as the python open function output?

Currently I have the python producing this byte string: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

and I would like the same in PHP output but all I seem to get is a repeating amount of this symbol: � (Null bytes)

any ideas on how I could produce a byte string like the one in python but in php? Is there a way to use the python open function in PHP or reproduce the function so it can be used in PHP?

This is my basic php code:

```
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
```

This is my basic python code for reading the file:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
f.read()
```

Comment: "all I seem to get is a repeating amount of this symbol" -- well, yes. Python is returning a *byte string* containing a bunch of `\x00` bytes (those are `NUL` bytes). PHP doesn't really have byte strings so it's returning a regular string and your browser is trying to render those NUL bytes. There aren't many fonts that have a glyph to render NUL characters, so they'll render the "unknown character" symbol `�` instead. You could pass the string through `bin2hex()` to get the hexadecimal representation for each character.

Comment: I need the exact same output as python, without it the following code I have which unpacks the data fails. Ive tried using bin2hex() and my unpacking code fails, henc why ive asked if theres a way to reproduce the python output. Ill edit the question.

Comment: `$contents` should contain the exact same binary data as the result from `f.read()`. The suggestion to use `bin2hex` was because you wanted a string output. If you’re going to unpack binary data, use the raw `fread()` response.

Comment: Then my formatting for unpacking must be wrong, though I have checked this and it should be, I will ask another question instead to check if the formatting is correct. Do you have any materials or advice for converting a python unpacking format to php unpacking format?

Comment: I have too little experience dealing with packed binary data in Python to say anything about that. Personally I'd open both [the Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) and [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php#refsect1-function.pack-parameters) side-by-side and compare.